# Best way to deploy a python code (make a web app from py code)

Tags: python, web-applications

I am working on a project written in python.
The goal is to have a user friendly calculator-type app (user enters desired values and the app gives the result based on the user input).

Now the python part is not the problem. The problem is I have no clue what to use to deploy the code.
I know about and worked with Bokeh, Streamlit, HoloViews, etc. Those solutions are not the best for what I want to achieve.

What would be your suggestion?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Platform.sh might be worth looking into. There is a lot more that goes into choosing something like this, how many visitors do you expect, price, efficeny...
PythonAnywhere might be the easiest if you are not looking to set up db, backend in flask/django...

Comment: Thanks a lot, James! I was looking into it but seems that all those services (Streamlit, Heroku etc.) would claim a copyright to your code in a way. I was aiming more in the direction of a standalone thing that I can run on my own website. (Not I am not a programmer but a scientist)

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes more sense. The front end of your project (part people interact with), is that made in python or JS/HTML in a web browser?

Comment: I work in Python (I do know some HTML)

Comment: This article might be worth a read... Sounds like it is not possible with what you are currently doing
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109572/can-i-create-a-desktop-python-gui-application-and-run-it-as-a-web-app

Comment: Not that it can not be done, just that running python based webapp how you want to is very difficult. My understanding is your option are to: either hire a programmer, offer the app as a downloadable file or learn web development. 
I will be the first to admit though that this is not my area of expertise. I have deployed a few python web apps before, but using Django an java script front end. 
Sorry if this is not much help :/

Comment: I see. No problem, this IS very useful! If I find a way I will share it here for sure.
Happy holidays :)